# Input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Tags: python

Can someone please help? I just started and it's not working:

```
myName = input("Hi, what is your name?")
myVar = input("Hello", myName,", how are you?")

if(myVar == "Good"):
    print("That's good!")

if(myVar == "Bad"):
    print ("Oh well")
```

Comment: The error message is clear; `input` only take a single argument, the prompt string, you're passing it three.

Answer (score 5):

Here is your problem:

```
input("Hello", myName,", how are you?")
```

The `input` function takes only one argument, the prompt. Here you are passing three. Python doesn't know what to do with the other two.

Pass one argument instead:

```
input("Hello " + myname + ", how are you?")
```

Comment: Or, if you really need `print`-style "magic formatting", you can always `print("Hello", myName, ", how are you?", end='')` and then `myVar = input()`. (Although you really _don't_ want `print`-style magic formatting here, because that'll give you a space before the comma…)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this solves your problem

`myVar = input("Hello"+ myName + "how are you?")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it into one argument instead of 3.Try this. i have had a similar error before and this did the trick!

```
myVar = input("Hello" + myName + "how are you")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could just do:

```
print("Hello,",myName,"How are you?")
myVar=input()
```

works just fine